# Append HTML table to another table

Tags: sencha-touch, sencha-touch-2

In my Sencha Touch 2 application I have an HTML table in a view which has its ID. What I'm trying to do is do some actions, load store, create another table and append it to the existing table - without changing the view. I have no problems with making the request, creating the second table on the fly, etc, however I need to figure out how one table can be appended to another in terms of Sencha Touch? Is there an "appendTo()" function like, say, jQuery has and how can I use it? I basically need to get the table by its ID and append the new table to it. But don't know how to do that in Sencha Touch 2. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

It depends what your view extends but if it's extending an [xtype:panel](http://docs.sencha.com/touch/2-0/#!/api/Ext.Panel) then you can use [getHtml()](http://docs.sencha.com/touch/2-0/#!/api/Ext.Panel-method-getHtml) to get the existing content and then [setHtml()](http://docs.sencha.com/touch/2-0/#!/api/Ext.Panel-method-setHtml) to update it.